# How can I create a ggplot with a regression line based on the predicted values of a glm?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, glm

I am creating a ggplot and I would like to add in a regression line, I have tried using `geom_smooth`. But the trouble now is that I would like to add this line using the predicted values of my response variable which I retrieved from the `predict()` function.

I was just wondering if anyone knows how I could do this? I have tried adding:

```
geom_smooth(predicted.values ~ data$predictor1 + data$predictor2)
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. It returns:

> Warning messages: 1: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values
> (stat_smooth).  2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: variable
> lengths differ (found for 'data$predictor1')  3: Removed 2 rows
> containing missing values (geom_point).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please provide a minimum [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people help you. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683977/add-regression-lines-from-predictive-values-in-ggplot) already addresses the question, and this blog by @aosmith answers your question with both `predict()` and `geom_smooth()`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a regression line from a glm, you can do it directly with `geom_smooth`, provided that you supply a list of appropriate arguments to the `method.args` parameter.

For example, suppose I have the following count data and wish to carry out a Poisson regression using `glm`:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y = rpois(100, seq(1, 5, length.out = 100)))
```

Then my model would look like this:

```
model <- glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = poisson)
```

And if I want to plot my data with a regression line, I can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = poisson),
              fill = "deepskyblue4", color = "deepskyblue4", linetype = 2)
```

[image]

If instead you want to use the output of `predict` directly, you could do something like:

```r
predicted.values <- predict(model, type = "response")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted.values), linetype = 2)
```

[image]